# What does "round pegs" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From the film *Forrest Gump:*

> FORREST: Now, for some reason, I fit in the Army like one of them **round pegs**.  It's not really hard. You just make your bed real neat and remember to stand up straight, and always answer every question with, "Yes, Drill Sergeant!"

What does "round pegs" mean here?

[Quote cited on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/characters/nm0648416#:%7E:text=Forrest%20Gump%20%3A%20%5Bnarrates%5D%20Now,%22Yes%2C%20drill%20sergeant.%22)

Comment: To close voters: this is unsearchable because the original expression is about a "square peg", and there's no mention of "hole" to search for with it, so I'm leaving this open

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a quirky allusion to the idiomatic [***square peg in a round hole***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20square%20peg%20in%20a%20round%20hole#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20a%20square%20peg,she%20made%20some%20new%20friends.), used to refer to a situation where someone is not<sup>1</sup> well suited to their circumstances.
Which is almost always that way round - people don't normally talk about being *a **round** peg in a **square** hole*.

But Gump is saying that he ***is*** a metaphorical "round peg" - with the implication that for most people, being in the Army is like being a square peg in a round hole, so they ***don't*** fit in. But Gump ***does*** fit in (being in the army is weird, but Gump is weird too, *in a compatible way*).

In case it's not obvious, the *specific* type of "weirdness" alluded to above is essentially that both Gump and the army in general are ***stupid, unimaginative, literal-minded***.

---

[Here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22happy%20early%20experience%20in%20policing%22) another example that more explicitly clarifies the intended sense of being "a good fit":

> *I had a very happy early experience in policing in that my first two years everything fitted into place. The concept of being a round peg in a round hole. **I was that round peg**. This was my career.*

---

<sup>1</sup> The *established idiomatic usage* refers to someone who ***doesn't*** fit in. Where Gump's "quirkily reversed" version means he ***does*** fit in (specifically with *army life*, not necessarily *life in general*).

Comment: Might this fine answer better serve the OP or some readers if fronted with a straightforward "It means someone who fits in easily. More specifically here, it means that Forrest Gump was readily accepted by others and has no problem becoming part of the Army."--or similar?

Comment: Might the first sentence also benefit from reducing/eliminating the chance that some readers may not be sure which noun phrase is *used:* "allusion" or "idiomatic ..."? This too is offered as at attempt at refined feedback on an elegant and sublime piece of text. Happy to delete these and so de-clutter if I'm pinged after @Fum 's considered them.

Comment: @JimReynolds: Thanks for the feedback. But regarding ***used***  - in the unlikely event that a reader initially interpreted my *[which is] **used** [in the cited context] to refer to a situation where someone is not well suited to their circumstances* as referring back to the ***allusion*** rather than the ***idiomatic** [usage]* itself, I think they'd surely realise the error by the time they'd read the next two sentences (which *only* make sense if it's understood that I was summarising the idiomatic usage there). *And* the text before ***used*** is a hot link to that definition.

Comment: ...but regarding "**someone who fits in easily**" - that's not *quite* accurate here. I emphasised *Gump is weird too, **in a compatible way*** because we shouldn't assume Gump "fits in easily" ***everywhere***. I've seen the movie, and I can assure you the character gets on my nerves even when I know he's just an actor playing a part (I'd *really* hate to have to interact with someone like that in real life! :) The point being made is that his character *fits in well **with the army*** (if you like that sort of thing). Effectively, it's a "dig" by the scriptwriters.

Comment: ...but please leave the comments. Anything that gets people thinking about the meanings of words is worth hanging onto, imho.